# Why is sodium p-toluenesulfonate used as a supporting electrolyte in polypyrrole synthesis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrochemistry, polymers

First, some preamble: I'm currently working on my thesis, which is about the electropolymerization of polypyrrole onto carbon fiber felt. My methodology, for the most part, follows a paper by one of my professors and a dissertation by one of his students. Both of them use sodium p-toluenesulfonate (NaPTS) as a supporting electrolyte during synthesis, which is the standard for other papers I've read on the topic.

Why is NaPTS the standard supporting electrolyte in PPy synthesis? Is it because pyrrole has limited solubility in water and p-toluenesulfonic acid increases its solubility? Are there any other electrolytes that would be suitable or even better for this application?

Thank you!